# Firebase Auth Error: [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17020 null

Tags: java, android, flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies

I have a problem since I want to try Firebase Authentication with a mobile phone

I followed the Docs' instructions and made it step-by-step

1. create a flutter project
2. create Firebase project
3. connect with SHA-1 and SHA-256
4. Download JSON file in `android/app/`
5. enable the phone sign-in method from Firebase console
6. doing the additional configuration for Android
7. and put two numbers for testing

now in my code, I'm prompt the user to enter his phone number and pass it as an argument to the following function

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Future phoneAuth() async {
    debugPrint('+2${phoneAuthController.text.trim().toString()}');
    debugPrint('Started Auth'); 
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: '+2${phoneAuthController.text.trim().toString()}', // +2 is the country code
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
// from here code skipped 
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        debugPrint('verificationCompleted');
        await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        debugPrint('credential.smsCode is : ${credential.smsCode}');
        debugPrint('credential.verificationId is : ${credential.verificationId}');
        debugPrint('credential.accessToken is : ${credential.accessToken}');
        debugPrint('credential.providerId is : ${credential.providerId}');
        debugPrint('credential.signInMethod is : ${credential.signInMethod}');
        debugPrint('credential.token is : ${credential.token}');
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        debugPrint('verificationFailed');
        debugPrint('e.credential is : ${e.credential}');
        debugPrint('e.phoneNumber is : ${e.phoneNumber}');
        debugPrint('e.tenantId is : ${e.tenantId}');
        debugPrint('e.code is : ${e.code}');
        debugPrint('e.message is : ${e.message}');
        debugPrint('e.plugin is : ${e.plugin}');
        debugPrint('e.stackTrace is : ${e.stackTrace}');
      },
      codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) async {
        debugPrint('codeSent');
        String smsCode = '123456';
        PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
            verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);
        await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
        debugPrint('codeAutoRetrievalTimeout');
      },
    );
// code return worked here again
    debugPrint('Finished Auth');
  }
```

here's the debug console output

```
I/flutter (21979): +201090461339
I/flutter (21979): Started Auth
I/flutter (21979): Finsihed Auth
W/System  (21979): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System  (21979): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(21979): e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
W/System  (21979): ClassLoader referenced unknown path: system/framework/mediatek-cta.jar
I/System.out(21979): e:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mediatek.cta.CtaHttp
3
E/FirebaseAuth(21979): [SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17020 null
```

my dependences in pubspec.yaml

```
firebase_core: ^2.15.1
firebase_auth: ^4.9.0
```

kotlen version

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
```

android\app\build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.5.0"))
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth")
}
```

android\app\src\main\AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
...
<application ... android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

how can I solve this problem? It took a long time from me.

Comment: Hiii! Did you solved this problem ?

Comment: no, I skipped it